# cout incorrectly prints out the Vector of strings

Tags: c++, string, visual-c++, vector

The below code snippet is printing the first letter of the words rather than the entire words. But when I debug it, I see the data array containing the whole words. Can anyone explain why.

```
vector<string> data;
vector.resize(x);
for(int i=0; i<x; i++)
{
  infile.getline(&data[i][0],32,'\n');
  cout<<data[i];
  if(infile.fail()) break;
}
```

Comment: `infile.getline(&data[i][0],32,'\n');` This exhibits undefined behavior. You promise to `getline` that `&data[i][0]` points to a buffer at least 32 bytes large - but it doesn't. `data[i]` is an empty `string`.

Comment: I don't quite understand what you are saying. Can you give a code sample of how it is supposed to  be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You exceed the bounds of the string. `data[i]` is an empty string, writing `&data[i][0]` causes undefined behaviour.

The code could be replaced by:

```
for (int i = 0; i < x; i++)
{
    if ( !getline(infile, data[i]) )
        break;

    if ( data[i].size() > 32 )
        data[i].resize(32);

    cout << data[i];
}
```

Note that this also fixes an error where you do `cout << data[i];` again after an input failure.

Comment: `writing &data[i][0] causes undefined behaviour.` Not true - writing that does not by itself cause undefined behavior. `s[s.size()]` is well defined. Modifying `s[size()]` is what leads to undefined behavior.

Comment: @Matt But I want to limit it to 32 characters which is why I want to use fstream_object.getline()

Comment: @user3651245 what do you want to happen when a line is longer than 32?  discard the remainder, or take it in the next read?

Comment: @user3651245 ok, updated my answer. It would also be possible to resize the string to 32, read into it, then resize the string again to fit if it was smaller, then read and discard any remaining characters; however that would be a lot more complicated code for dubious benefit.